# Preview files in browser instead of downloading in PHP

Tags: php, file, browser

I want to preview files in browser instead of downloading it from URL. Currently pdf files open in browser but other (txt, docs) don't. They get downloaded. Below is my code:

```
$file = 'https://URL_OF_FILES/some.txt';
$filename = 'some.txt';

header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

echo @readfile($file);
```

I've also tried by file get content method but still it's downloading.

Comment: essentially if the browser is displaying it it is downloaded

Comment: @RamRaider actually I don't want it to be downloaded on users system or on server each time the URL of file is hit from code. I want it to be displayed/previewed it in browser.